# Java process gc log file rotation not working

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a Java process with the following garbage collection flags enabled:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc:/var/logs/gc-%t.log
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:GCLogFileSize=20m
```

The garbage collection log files are getting created successfully but for some reason once the number of log files reached 5 files, the rotation didn't happen where the oldest log file gets cleared out and overwritten with the latest garbage collection logs. Since I have the flag `-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5` on, I expected the number of files to be always limited to 5 files.

For some additional context, here is a sample output of the log files from a `ls -l` command of the log directory:

```
$ ls -l logs/
total 39276
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  167053 Jun 11 07:29 gc-2022-06-11_00-40-46.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 5920573 Jun 12 07:27 gc-2022-06-11_07-31-19.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 3153322 Jun 13 07:26 gc-2022-06-12_07-31-15.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 9416297 Jun 14 07:30 gc-2022-06-13_07-29-58.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 5627519 Jun 15 07:27 gc-2022-06-14_07-31-24.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 6820185 Jun 16 07:27 gc-2022-06-15_07-31-22.log.0.current
-rw-r--r--  1 user user 9072354 Jun 16 17:44 gc-2022-06-16_07-31-18.log.0.current
```

As you can see above, there are already 7 log files being created. I expected the number of log files shown to be 5 at all time.
I am wondering if I am missing a specific flag or something about the way the flags are configured is preventing the log file rotation from happening successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I currently can't check it myself, so I have to tell this out of my head.

From what I remember is the log rotation only for log files with the same name root:

```
gc.log.0
gc.log.1
gc.log.2.current
gc.log.3
gc.log.4
```

But in your case, the name root is the `gc` plus a time stamp. So when the maximum size for a single log file is reached, a new file with a new root is created instead of a new "rotated" file.

When I am right, you should change your configuration like this:

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-Xloggc:/var/logs/gc.log
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:GCLogFileSize=20m
```

Check it!